# jquery select box (dropdown), load first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown select boy with a few images.

I can get the images to load when the user changes value, but I want the View All to load right when the page is viewed.. I know I can do this a few different ways but I would prefer that it just loads right away since the value is specified.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#image").change(function() {
     $("#imagePreview").empty();
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#image").val()  + "\" />");
   });
 });


<select name="image" id="image" class="inputbox" size="1">
   <option value="imageall.jpg" selected> - All - </option>
   <option value="image1.jpg">image1.jpg</option>
   <option value="image2.jpg">image2.jpg</option>
   <option value="image3.jpg">image3.jpg</option>
</select>

<div id="imagePreview">
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28UwU/)

Even if you view the Fiddle demo, you will see it won't load anything until you select image1 etc.

I want the imageall.jpg to load right when someone views fiddle.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change event fires when the select element value changes of course you can fire it yourself if you wanted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#image").change(function() {
     $("#imagePreview").empty();
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#image").val()  + "\" />");
   }).change();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28UwU/1/

Comment: If wanted, could I change this whole function into a object or a variable? so it would not conflict with other code... ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: could i wrap the jquery code you presented in a var Wrapper = function 
();

like this
$(document).ready(function() {
     var Wrapper = function() {
 $("#image").change(function() {
     $("#imagePreview").empty();
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#image").val()  + "\" />");
   }).change();
  };
 });

or would that not work?

Comment: You could, but I don't see how it would conflict with other code.

Answer (score 1):

[@Musa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353011/musa) has posted an interesting answer of triggering the `.change()` event on load, but it might be complicated if you have other functions bound to the `.change()` event that you wouldn't want to trigger, should you modify or update your code.

My approach would be calling a function instead. The function takes advantage of chaining available in jQuery, as well as construct the `<img />` element as an object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgPrev = function(imgSrc) {
        $('#imagePreview')
        .empty()
        .append($('<img />', {
            src: imgSrc,
            alt: ''
        }));
    };

    // Update image preview when <select> is updated
    $('#image').change(function() {
        imgPrev($(this).val());
    });

    // Update image preview on load
    imgPrev($('#image').find('option[selected]').val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/28UwU/5/

Comment: could you not use the     imgPrev($('#image').find('option[selected]').val());
at the begining of the code?? 

so the difference between you and musa is that he is not declaring a whole function as you are calling it a var img Prev which is the fuction

Comment: @op1001 It does not matter: JS is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can try handling the load for your div tag in the document.ready function.

> $('#image').load('@Url.Action("GetAllImages","ImageController")');