# jQuery select (Dropdown) populate from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I currently have this here working..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#image").change(function() {
     $("#imagePreview").empty();
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#image").val()  + "\" />");
   });
 });


<select name="image" id="image" class="inputbox" size="1">
   <option value="imageall.jpg" selected> - All - </option>
   <option value="image1.jpg">image1.jpg</option>
   <option value="image2.jpg">image2.jpg</option>
   <option value="image3.jpg">image3.jpg</option>
</select>

<div id="imagePreview">
</div>
```

from this previous question:

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215078/jquery-select-box-dropdown-load-first-value/24215099?noredirect=1#comment37392082_24215099)

I was wondering how can I populate the   from a jQuery Array instead?

How could I do that? So basically the values and name from an array

This is the example in Fiddle i will be using [Example Working](http://jsfiddle.net/28UwU/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using javascript and jquery, to populate related select boxes with array structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/using-javascript-and-jquery-to-populate-related-select-boxes-with-array-structu)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to retrieve names and values from JSON array this way.

```
var image_maps = {image1: "image1.jpg", image2: "image2.jpg"};
$.each(image_maps , function(name, value) {
    alert("name: " + name + " value: " + value);
});
```

Comment: Please accompany you code with explanatory comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
function populateSelect(el, items) {
    el.options.length = 0;
    if (items.length > 0)
        el.options[0] = new Option('please select', '');
    $.each(items, function () {
        el.options[el.options.length] = new Option(this.name, this.value);
    });
}
```

As seen here:
[Using javascript and jquery, to populate related select boxes with array structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/using-javascript-and-jquery-to-populate-related-select-boxes-with-array-structu)